# Firefox page-mod - "contentScript":null

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm doing the [`page-mod` tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod).

Here's my code:
`main.js`

```
var tag = 'p'
var data = require('sdk/self').data
var pageMod = require('sdk/page-mod')

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: '*',
    contentScriptFile: data.url('element-getter.js'),
    onAttach: attachHandler
})

function attachHandler(worker) {
    console.log('worker ', worker)
    worker.port.emit('getElements', tag)
    worker.port.on('gotContent', function(content) {
        console.log('received content ', content)
    })
}
```

`element-getter.js`:

```
self.port.on('getElements', function(tag) {
    console.log('received tag ', tag)
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(tag)
    console.log('found elements ', elements)
    for (var i=0; i< elements.length; i++) {
        self.port.emit('gotContent', elements[i].innerHTML)
    })
})
```

(Also available in [github.com/findjashua/pgmod](https://github.com/findjashua/pgmod))

It only logs the first message on the terminal, and none on the browser console. From the message, you can see that it thinks the `contentScript` is null. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is what gets logged on the terminal:

```
console.error: pgmod:
  Message: SyntaxError: syntax error
console.log: pgmod: worker  constructor {"contentScriptFile":"resource://jid1-kkjpd9s1yzxe9g-at-jetpack/pgmod/data/element-getter.js","contentScript":null,"port":{}}
```

Comment: Not sure why you get no log messages at all?! When I just tried that code it gave me a bunch of log messages! Your page-mod included only `*.mozilla.org`, maybe you didn't browse a `mozilla.org` website for forgot to adjust that `include` filter? After the initial messages, there is an error, of course, `TypeError: elements.forEach is not a function`, which is to be expected as `getElementsByTagName` does not return an array with a `.forEach`, but a `NodeList`.

Comment: Wow, that's strange. I updated the code (use a for loop instead of forEach). Could you please try it again and let me know the last message it logs on the console?

Comment: Could you upload a bit-exact copy of `element-getter.js` as on your disk somewhere (not just copy-paste it). I suspect that file is broken (e.g. broken encoding). As your console output shows, there is a syntax error reported without line number, and that usually indicated the JS parser did reject the file altogether.

Comment: do you mean upload file to dropbox or something?

Comment: Yeah, something like dropbox, or create a github, bitbucket and/or gist repo (etc) and commit without changing line encodings (matters when you are on windows). If it is indeed an encoding problem, at least check that your editor (whatever that may be) writes files as ASCII or UTF-8 *w/o BOM* (well, even the Window ANSI code page should work most of the time), but not UTF-8 with BOM or any UTF-16/UTF-32 or eastern encoding like BIG5.

Comment: here's the github repo: https://github.com/findjashua/pgmod. I'll have to google around on checking the encoding (I'm using Sublime Text), though I've never had a problem with it before.

Comment: it's utf-8, but I don't see anything about BOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I got too distracted by the `SyntaxError`. It is a `SyntaxError`, but not due to encoding.

From your repo:

```
self.port.on('getElements', function(tag) {
    console.log('received tag ', tag)
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(tag)
    console.log('found elements ', elements)
    for (var i=0; i< elements.length; i++) {
        self.port.emit('gotContent', elements[i].innerHTML)
    }) // <-- trailing parenthesis, left-over from having .forEach in there before 
})
```

After fixing this by removing the trailing parenthesis, the code works for me.

Comment: Thanks! The statements are getting logged in the terminal, but they still don't show up in the browser console. Are they showing up there for you?

Comment: Missed that bit of your question. This is expected, [using `cfx run` will not log to the Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/console), only installing the add-on XPI manually in the browser will (but will by default not log anything less important than `.error`, also explained in the docs).